# How to display a mobile bill by scanning a nfc tag in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, nfc

I am new to mobile programming.I have a use case where i need to display a bill in mobile browser when i scan a nfc tag using an iphone(with inbuilt nfc chip).

My understanding is that the nfc tag needs to be encoded with  a API(url) which will calculate the  cost of the bill when the nfc tag  is scanned using the iphone. But i am unaware how to display the bill in mobile browser since the API url is invoked by the nfc chip and not by the browser. Any tips or pointers on how to display the bill in the browser will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The NFC Tag needs to NDEF formatted and be written with an NDEF message consisting of 3 records.

1. URI Record Type representing http://example.com
2. Recommended Action Record
3. Title Record
   The NDEF message content as follows. Customise it to your URL and title.
   `----------
   Offset Content      Length Explanation
   0   0xD1        1 NDEF header. TNF = 0x01(Well Known Type). SR=1, MB=1, ME=1
   1   0x02        1 Record name length (2 bytes)
   2   0x30        1 Length of the Smart Poster data (48 bytes)
   3   “Sp”        2 The record name
   5   0x81        1 NDEF header. TNF = 0x01, SR=0, MB=1, ME=0
   6   0x01        1 Record name length (1 byte)
   7   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C   4 The length of the URI payload (12 bytes) (long format)
   11  “U”         1 Record type: “U”
   12  0x03        1 Abbreviation: “http://”
   13  “example.com”  11 The URI itself.
   24  0x11        1 NDEF record header (SR=1, TNF=0x01)
   25  0x03        1 The length of the record name
   26  0x01        1 The length of the “act” payload.
   27  “act”       3 Record type: “act”
   30  0x00        1 Action = Launch browser
   31  0x11        1 NDEF record header (SR=1, TNF=0x01)
   32  0x01        1 Length of the record name
   33  0x12        1 Length of the record payload (18 bytes)
   34  “T”         1 Record type: “T” (=Text)
   35  0x05        1 Status byte for the Text (UTF-8, five-byte code)
   36  “en-US”     5 ISO Language code: US-English
   41  “Hello, world” 12 The text: “Hello world”, encoded in UTF-8.
   ----------`
   I believe Iphone should behave similar to Android that upon reading this tag, it launches the browser loading the specified URL.